# Bootstrap обтекание текста

Tags: bootstrap

Добрый вечер! Не могу сделать обтекание текста нормально.

Вот что сейчас имею. То есть `col-lg-5` картинка на половину блока.

`col-lg-7` - текст справа от картинки

`col-lg-12` - текст во всю ширину контейнера

Мне нужно как-то избавиться от `col-lg-12`, чтобы текст в одну колонку писать и он под изображением уже шел во всю длину.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
        <div class="container">
        <div class="round-sep"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <div class="romb">
                </div>
                <div class="romb-date">
                    <div class="romb-text">
                        13.04.2015
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="romb-img">
                    <img src="img/test.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <div class="record-text">
                    <h1>Заголовок</h1>
                    <div class="record-text-h1-sep"></div>
                    <h2>Заголовок 2</h2>
                    <div class="record-text-sep"></div>
                    <p>
                        Длинный текст
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="text">
                <p>
                    Длинный текст
                </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что стоит это делать? А если в результате под изображением останется только одно слово (картинка большая или текст слишком маленький)? Чем Вас не устраивает текущая разметка?

Comment: При адаптации под WordPress придется как-то делить текст записи, что очень плохо.

Comment: С WP не работал. Никак не получится дать пользователю возможность задать два текста?

Comment: Конечно можно написать плагин, но это будет лишним и бесполезным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понял суть вопроса..Вам нужно, что бы текст после обтекания картинки был во всю ширину? Так просто не задавайте ему колонку, но оставьте в `.row`.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5">
        <img src="" style="width:100%">
    <div/>
    <div>
        Длинный текст
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос, решение не идеальное, т.е. приходится игнорировать основные элементы верстки на Bootstrap. Но все же это выход.

http://dabblet.com/gist/7766924